How can I align my bootstrap carousel with the rest of the content on the page?
can someone help me understand why my carousel is still displaying on the left side as opposed to properly align with the rest of the content on the page. Please ping me if anyone can help, I did everything right, but I can't seem to understand why it's not working
I place the entire div in a class "container" and it still not working.
This is the code
<div class="container">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="./couple.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="couple">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./dog.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="dog">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./family.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="family">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>


Can you add your code to reproduce it ?

Please provide your code or add it to a playground so we can check.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I added the in the original post above. Please take a look.
